# Read an XML file from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

I want to read an XML file stored on my Azure Blob storage in a Jupyter notebook (PySpark3 to be exact).

I came across [this tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/08/25/getting-data-into-azure-notebooks-jupyter-in-the-classroom/) - but am having little luck.

Basi,cally it complains it cannot find `azure.storage` - from the line `from azure.storage.blob import BlobService`.

I've tried:

```
! pip install --user azure.storage
```

with no luck.

Could someone kindly help:

- That above throws a syntax error when trying to install
- Otherwise, is there some clearer instructions on how to get a file from Azure Blob Storage in as a Dataframe for me to use?

Any guidance appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What service do you use on Azure? Azure Jupyter Notebook https://notebooks.azure.com or Azure Databricks?

Answer (score 2):

There are two solutions to get the xml content from a blob.

Solution 1. To get the blob url with sas token by Azure Storage Explorer, and then to get the xml content by `requests`.

Fig 1.1. Right click on the `a-sample.xml` blob, and click the option `Get Shared Access Signature`.

[image]

Fig 1.2. Select the option `UTC` and enable the `Read` permission, then to `Create`.

[image]

Fig 1.3. `Copy` the blob url with sas token.

[image]

Fig 1.4. Install `requests` via `!pip install requests` and get the xml content.

[image]

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('<the blob url with sas token copied from Azure Storage Explorer>')
xml_content = resp.text
print(xml_content)
```

Solution 2. Actually, Azure Storage SDK for Python is named `azure-storage`, so you can follow the figure below to do what you want.

Fig 2.1. Install Azure Python Storage via `!pip install azure-storage`, and get the content by the code. Please refer to the GitHub repo [`Azure/azure-storage-python`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python).

[image]

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
container_name = '<container name>'
blob_name = '< the xml blob name, such as a-sample.xml>'
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=account_name, account_key=account_key)
xml_content = block_blob_service.get_blob_to_text(container_name, blob_name).content
print(xml_content)
```

I did these below in [Azure Jupyter Notebook](https://notebooks.azure.com/), it also works on Azure Databricks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for that very detailed answer - however I'm unable to do the `!pip install azure-storage`. Jupyter is installed via Azure. Do I need to go to Jupyter terminal to run that line? I'm presuming it doesnt go within the notebook itself?

Comment: Infact I just tried this on a second Jyupter notebook (locally on anaconda) and now I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'` :p
Do you have a complete notebook I could take a look at?